# A Question about Quantization and Partition Function

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-mechanics

I have a question about quantization and partition function, which sound a little bit inappropriate. But I still want to ask for help.

I think that quantization is a unitary representation of the classical symmetry. And the associated partition function is the character of the operator of time evolution.

Does it sounds correct or not?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be helpful if you took the time and wrote down in some detail the exact definition you are using (for example: what do you mean with quantization? What symmetry are you talking about? ...)

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for the comment. I will try to write down some details tomorrow.